# Django NoReverseMatch Argument

Tags: python, django

Doesn't find a suitable url from the list(I assume it takes a string for a tuple)

> ```
> NoReverseMatch at /decision/livingrooms/kitchen/
>     Reverse for 'style' with arguments '('provans',)' not found. 1 pattern(s) tried:
> ```
>
> ['decision/livingrooms/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/(?P[-a-zA-Z0-9_]+)/$']

Template

```
<ul class="menu menu_interiors">
            {% for room in rooms %}
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:room' room.slug %}">{{ room.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}


        </ul>
<ul class="menu menu_styles">
            {% for style in styles %}
                <li class="menu__item menu__item_interiors"><a href="{% url 'decision:style' style.slug %}">{{ style.name }}</a></li>
            {% endfor %}
        </ul>
```

urls.py

```
from django.urls import path
from .views import ContactView
from . import views

app_name = 'decision'

urlpatterns = [
    path('livingrooms/', ContactView.as_view(), name='livingrooms'),
    path('livingrooms/<slug:rmslg>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('livingrooms/<slug:rmslg>/<slug:stslg>/', views.style, name='style'),
]
```

views.py

```
def room(request, rmslg):
    styles = Room.objects.get(slug=rmslg).styles.all()
    print(len(styles))
    return render(request, 'decision/residentialInteriors.html', {"styles": styles})


def style(request, stslg):
    style = Style.objects.get(slug=stslg)
    return render(request, 'decision/residentialInteriors.html', {"style": style})
```

Comment: When you type `"{% url 'decision:style' style.slug %}"`, you're only giving one arg to your URL. Shouldn't you give 2? One for `rmslg` and one for `stslg` to match `'livingrooms/<slug:rmslg>/<slug:stslg>/'`

Comment: Jordan Kowal, oh yes i don't notice thank you. Could tou remind me how to give 2 arguments correct in template

Comment: I think it works like this: `{% url 'decision:style' rmslg=room.slug stslg=style.slug %}`

Answer (score 0):

Change the last path to accept only one parameter.

From:

```
path('livingrooms/<slug:rmslg>/<slug:stslg>/', views.style, name='style'),
```

To:

```
path('styles/<slug:stslg>/', views.style, name='style'), # Since your view only accepts one parameter, the URL should capture only one as well.
```

Final Result:

```
urlpatterns = [
    path('livingrooms/', ContactView.as_view(), name='livingrooms'),
    path('livingrooms/<slug:rmslg>/', views.room, name='room'),
    path('styles/<slug:stslg>/', views.style, name='style'), # Since your view only accepts one parameter, the URL should capture only one as well.
]
```